# PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR: index row requires 13904 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, text

I have one field

```
t.text "po_description", null: false
```

and i'm trying to save 200-300 lines of text in this field and getting overflow error :-

> PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR: index row requires 13904 bytes,
>   maximum size is 8191 : INSERT INTO "po_terms" ("company_id",
>   "po_description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
>   RETURNING "id"

Note: - i'm using postgresql db

How to fix it, any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 9):

The error message says exactly what the problem is. You have indexed the "po_description" column and it exceeds the maximum index size.

An index on such large columns is unlikely to be useful anyway. Simplest solution is just to remove it.

Comment: do you mean to remove indexing from `po_description` column?

Comment: Yes. If you need to search on this column, either use full text search or index just the first couple of characters of the field (an index on a substring expression). Use the same expression when searching the table.